# Traveling to Baja California, Mexico, what are the immigration/departure taxes?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, mexico, taxes

Traveling on a National Geographic trip from Los Angeles International Airport (LAX) to Baja California, Mexico.  I have never paid immigration taxes or departure taxes when flying to and from Mexico.

Is there such a tax for Baja California?

Comment: What is *Baja Mexico*?  I am aware of Baja California but not Baja Mexico.

Answer (score 2):

There is a departure tax and it is not always included in your airline ticket price, e.g. Thomson (british travel operator) does not include it in their offer. 
What does NAt Geo trip mean in detail? National Geographic is acting like a travel operator and you pay them for the trip? Than you should ask Nat. Geo. if the tax is included or not (or read the general terms and conditions).

Answer (score 1):

Baja is part of Mexico, so subject to similar taxes as other parts of Mexico.  Is there a departure tax, yes.  Will you pay it, essentially yes, but it is included in your airline ticket price, so nothing you have to worry about.

You likewise have paid "departure tax" in the past as well, but it was included in your airline ticket price, so something you didn't pay attention to.